# Google Calendar API returns Events that no longer exist

Tags: google-calendar-api

Using Calendar API V3, I've noticed that the number of events returned is not consistent with the number of events that appear on a given Calendar. It appears this issue occurs for recurring events that users have moved to a different day, or deleted on a given day. Calendar doesn't seem to recognize this and still returns them. Both Events:get and Events:list show the nonexistent events.

Is there any workaround or means of identifying that an event returned by the API does not actually appear on the (web interface) calendar?

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing now where an event that is nowhere on an actual calendar anymore is coming back through the API and the status on it ="confirmed" rather than cancelled.

Comment: This was along time ago, but did you find any solution? I have hit the same problem with the Android Calendar API.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that when you set `singleEvents` to `true` the problem doesn't occur. It depends on your use case whether this is an acceptable workaround.

Documentation on `singleEvents`:

> Whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring events, but not the underlying recurring events themselves. Optional. The default is False.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Answer (score 0):

You can .setShowDeleted 'false' in the request. Example Java:

```
Events events = calendarService.events().list(PRIMARY_CALENDAR_ID)
                .setShowDeleted(false)
                .setPageToken(nextPageToken).execute();
```

But note also that:

> Cancelled instances of recurring events (but not the underlying
>   recurring event) will still be included if showDeleted and
>   singleEvents are both False.

For further reading see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list