# How to filter-out rescheduled Android calendar events instances

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I have an app that reads all calendar event instances for a time range like this:

```
...
fun getEventsInstancesForMultipleCalendars(context: Context, calendarsIds: List<Long>, from: Instant, to: Instant): Cursor? {
    val builder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, from.toEpochMilli())
    ContentUris.appendId(builder, to.toEpochMilli())

    val selection = "${CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID} IN (${calendarsIds.joinToString(", ") { "?" }})"
    val selectionArgs = calendarsIds
        .map { it.toString() }
        .toTypedArray()

    return context.contentResolver.query(builder.build(), EVENTS_INSTANCES_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null)
}
```

Everything is working fine, except for rescheduled instances of some recurring events. Both the rescheduled and the original event instances end-up in the result.

How can I filter-out the original event instance, which is no longer valid? Google Calendar correctly does not display the original instance, so there must be a way to do this.

I loaded every column from the calendar and the only difference between these instances I see, is, that they have different `event_id` and different `_sync_id`. And the only connection between them is that the new, now valid instance, has `original_sync_id` set to the original's `_sync_id`. This OK for cases when both, the old and new, event instances fall between my time range. But how do I check, and filter-out, rescheduled events if the new instance is not in the time range? Is there any query parameter I could add to the `builder` that will filter-our rescheduled events?

Other properties like `deleted`, `visible`, `status`, etc. have the same values in both instances.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418429/google-calendar-api-returns-events-that-no-longer-exist) what you have tried?

Comment: @YancyGodoy I am using the [Android Calendar Provider APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) and I do not see an option for `singleEvents` there. How can I set it via the Android API?

The `showDeleted` is `false` by default, so that shouldn't be a problem.