# Android Calendar Provider API is returning deleted recurring events

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am using the [Android Calendar Provider API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider) to load events (just their instances). I have noticed that it is also returning deleted instances of a recurring event.

I am unable to distinguish them from the not-deleted instances because their status is not canceled and the deleted property is zero. I have loaded all the columns from the DB and I do not see any difference between deleted and not-deleted instances. I just load instances in a time range like this:

```
val builder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
ContentUris.appendId(builder, from.toEpochMilli())
ContentUris.appendId(builder, to.toEpochMilli())
...
val cur = context.contentResolver.query(builder.build(), EVENTS_INSTANCES_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null)
```

This looks similar to my other, not yet answered, [problem about rescheduled recurring instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860750/how-to-filter-out-rescheduled-android-calendar-events-instances), where they are both returned, the original and its rescheduled version.

The Google Calendar app does not display the deleted instances, so they are really deleted.

The Calendar REST API has an option to return single events, that looks like solves this problem, but I have not found a way to add this into the query for Android Calendar Provider API.

Is there a way to tell if an instance of a recurring calendar event was canceled/deleted/rescheduled via the Android Calendar Provider API?